# MiKTeX Package Manager not working after Windows 10 update

Tags: miktex, windows

Recently I allowed Windows 10 to perform a major update. But now there seems to be a problem with the MiKTeX automatic package installer. E.g. I want to use package skak. So I include

```
\usepackage{skak}
```

and start `pdflatex`. Then that dramatic orange box:

```
Do you want to allow this app from an unknown publisher to make changes to your device? MiKTeX Package Manager.
```

So I click `YES`. Then in the PDFLaTeX console:

```
! LaTeX Error: File `skak.sty' not found.
Type X to quit or <RETURN> to proceed, or enter new name. (Default extension: sty)
```

All I can do now is hit <kbd>RETURN</kbd>. Compilation continues with the now expected undefined control sequences. After the last one the dreaded window pops up

```
pdflatex.exe has stopped working ...
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! As a workaround, can you install the package with `MiKTeX Package Manager` (Admin, preferably)?

Comment: There is an option to enable/disable on-the-fly installation, check what is written in MiKTeX Settings -> General -> Package installation that this is suitably enabled.  Also might be worth synchronising the repository in MiKTEX Package Manager -> Repository -> Synchronize.

Comment: Here is a [related article](https://itvision.altervista.org/why-windows-10-sucks.html).

Comment: Belatedly: you might try completely uninstalling MikTEX and reinstalling the latest version. Something changed about the way the package manager works at some point in 2017, and this fixed the issue for me (running the update wizard did not).  It probably has nothing to do with Win 10.